# Set zoom extent to a certain layer failed using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, extents

I want to make "zoom to layer" set to my layer called layer_base. This layer's datasource is postgres and I connect it using URI.I try to use this code but after I run it, I got an error. Here my code :

```
        sql = "(SELECT * from gis.view_bidang_all where nama_desa = '"+text+"')"
        uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
        uri.setConnection("192.168.0.153", "5432", "db_pbb", "postgres", "postgres")
        uri.setDataSource("", sql, "geom", "", "nop")
        layer_base = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "Bidang", "postgres")
        #layer_base.setLayerTransparency(50)
        mySymbol1=QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'color':'#000000',
                                                'color_border':'#000000',
                                                'width_border':'0.17',
                                                'style':'no'})
        myRenderer = layer_base.rendererV2()
        myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)
        layer_base.triggerRepaint()
        #symbols = layer_base .rendererV2().symbols()
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer_base)
        self.mapCanvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.mapCanvas.setExtent(self.layer_base.extent())
```

And here errors that I've got :

```
2016-10-15T19:39:35 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/Users/septin/.qgis2/python/plugins\PBB\gis_pbb.py", line 225, in run
            self.mapCanvas.setExtent(self.layer_base.extent())
        AttributeError: PBB instance has no attribute 'layer_base'
```

Any ideas ?

I try to use `self.iface.setActiveLayer(layer_base)` and `self.iface.zoomToActiveLayer()` instead of use  `self.mapCanvas = QgsMapCanvas()` and `self.mapCanvas.setExtent(self.layer_base.extent())`. The result is the active layer already set to layer_base (I've more than one layers), but the zoom to layer doesn't work.

I already try to run this script using python console, and the "zoom to" works well. Still confused what's wrong, any ideas ?

Comment: Just remove the `self` from `layer_base`, in this way:         `self.mapCanvas.setExtent(layer_base.extent())`

Comment: I've removed `self` from `layer_base` and it didn't return error anymore, but the zoom doesn't working too, any other ideas GermánCarrillo ?

Comment: Is your layer valid? Check `layer_base.isValid()`
If so, try: `self.iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(layer_base.extent())`  and then `self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()`

Comment: I've try your suggestion, but still doesn't work